# How can I use a string parameter to specify an image for an iPhone table cell?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsstring, uiimage

I have an object `MObject` that is currently defined like so:

```
+ (id)objectWithType:(NSString*)type name:(NSString*)name code:(NSString*)code imageName:(NSString*)imageName
{
 UIImage *theImage = [[UIImage alloc] imageNamed:imageName];
 MObject *newObject = [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
 newObject.type = type;
 newObject.name = name;
 newObject.code = code;
 return newObject;
}
```

`imageName` is meant to contain the file name of the appropriate image `anImage.png`. Once I put that in, I need the UIImage object to be created so that it can be placed in `cell.imageView.image`.

I'm 1) unclear on whether the direction I've started to take (as shown above) is workable, 2) so far clueless as to how I can get this `UIImage` into my  in my `MainViewController`. I really appreciate any help you offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! I changed the code shown in my original post to:

```
+ (id)objectWithType:(NSString*)type name:(NSString*)name code:(NSString*)code imageName:(NSString*)imageName
{
 MObject *newObject = [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
 newObject.type = type;
 newObject.name = name;
 newObject.code = code;
 newObject.imageName = imageName;
 return newObject;
}
```

Then I added the following line to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imagedNamed:object.imageName];
```

And that's all it took!

Answer (score 0):

- (UIImage *)newImageFromResource:(NSString *)filename
  {
  NSString *str = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
  UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:str];
  return image;
  }

and Whenever you want to set Image

UIImage *img=[UIImage newImageFromResource:@"xyz.png"];

You can set img wherever you want & dont forget to release img

Comment: Could you explain where this should go in my code? What is it replacing? I'm having a hard time understanding your answer.